# Pandas Groupby with lambda gives some NANs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF where I'd like to create a new column with the difference of 2 other column values.

```
name    rate    avg_rate

A        10       3
B         6       5
C         4       3
```

I wrote this code to calculate the difference :

```
result= df.groupby(['name']).apply(lambda g: g.rate - g.avg_rate)

df['rate_diff']=result.reset_index(drop=True)

df.tail(3)
```

But I notice that some of the values calculated are NANs. What is the best way to handle this?

Output i am getting:

```
name    rate    avg_rate   rate_diff

A        10       3         NAN
B         6       5         NAN
C         4        3        NAN
```

Comment: `create a new column with the difference of 2 other column values`: this could be done with just `df["rate_diff"] = df.rate - df.avg_rate`. What's the groupby for, and what's your expected output?

Comment: @sacuL has a point. With this data there's no need to use `groupby` at all. Could you provide a larger sample of your data? This way we can understand why do you need the `groupby`. I've just run your code and it works fine for this three-rows dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `groupby` and `apply` then following should work,

```
res = df.groupby(['name']).apply(lambda g: g.rate - g.avg_rate).reset_index().set_index('level_1')
df = pd.merge(df,res,on=['name'],left_index = True, right_index=True).rename({0:'rate_diff'},axis=1)
```

However, as @sacuL suggested in the comments, you don't need to use groupby to calculate the difference as you are just going to get the difference by simply subtracting columns (side by side), and groupby apply will be overkill for this simple task.

```
df["rate_diff"] = df.rate - df.avg_rate
```